# Ext 5.1.3 grid not preserving scrollbar position after store load on remote sort

Tags: extjs

We have recently upgraded to Extjs 5.1.3 from 5.1.1

All the grids in the application have remote sort and some have both vertical and horizontal scroll bars.
After the upgrade none of the grids are able to preserve the scrollbar position after sort.

I have already tried preserveScrollOnReload: true , it is not working.

Since the issue is through out the application, any quick help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

ok after some debugging I was able to fix it by adding the below property to grid config.

preserveScrollOnReload: true

hope it helps.